# Magento 2 main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file error

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to load a simple template in the Magento 2 admin panel but the error I get in the system.log is:

```
main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'Test_Main::dashboard/index.phtml' in module: 'Test_Main' block's name: 'test.dashboard.index' [] []
```

My Controller class is:

```
Test\Main\Controller\Adminhtml\Dashboard\Index.php
```

My Block class is:

```
Test\Main\Block\Adminhtml\Dashboard.php
```

My layout file is:

```
Test\Main\view\adminhtml\layout\test_dashboard_index.xml
```

My template file is:

```
Test\Main\view\adminhtml\template\dashboard\index.phtml
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Folder for templates is Test\Main\view\adminhtml\ **templates** \dashboard\index.phtml not
 Test\Main\view\adminhtml\ **template** \dashboard\index.phtml